# How to make query fast in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm using below mentioned query returns 1400 records  its taking about  53 seconds to give results. Is there any way I can make it faster. but my employee master contain more 15,000 records and transaction_user_register contain 25,000 record. query record return 1400 records

```
   select 
       b.t_reg_id,
       b.version,
       b.device_imei,
       b.device_model,
       b.created_date, b.active,
       a.emp_id, 
       a.emp_code,
       a.role_id,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       concat('91',a.mobile_no) as mobileno, 
       c.role_code ,
       '' as Orgunit
   from
       employee_master a,
       transaction_user_register b,
       emp_role_master c
   where 
       a.emp_code=b.emp_code and 
       a.role_id=c.role_id 
   group by emp_code;
```

Comment: You might want to look into stored procedures when dealing with large amount of data involving CRUD.

Comment: InnoDB or MyISAM? Could you post my.cnf here?

Comment: If 1400 records in each table results in 53 seconds there's something seriously wrong with your installation.  Even if it's doing a full table scan that should take a few milliseconds.  Everything should fit easily in memory, and I don't see anything that's doing a cartesian join.  Is the system otherwise heavily loaded?

Comment: i am using mysql query browser

Comment: in the employee and transaction user master table contain more than 1,00,000 records

Comment: Please edit your post to include that information.  You said 1400 records in each table. Also please show what indexes exist. Without that information nobody can help you.

Comment: Explain out put can help more , i think you have no indexes

Comment: I think the problem is indexes. Try adding indexes on the emp_code and role_id columns and see if that speeds things up.

Comment: thank you so much i add the index to role_id and emp_code the output will speed up

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at indexes on your tables?

Also, perhaps a better structured query indicating the INNER JOINS would improve matters.

```
select b.t_reg_id,b.version,b.device_imei,b.device_model,b.created_date, b.active,
       a.emp_id, a.emp_code,a.role_id,first_name,last_name,concat('91',a.mobile_no) as
       mobileno, c.role_code ,'' as Orgunit
from
employee_master a
inner join transaction_user_register b
  on a.emp_code=b.emp_code
inner join emp_role_master c
  on a.role_id=c.role_id 
group by emp_code;
```